# How to add new page in itextsharp pdf generated using html table

Tags: c#, itext

Im generating a pdf with itextsharp

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = BuildData();
                    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

                    Document pdfDoc = new Document(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(288f, 144f), 20, 20, 40, 20);                  
                    pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);

                    //save 
                    System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(DestinationPath + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create); 

                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);

                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();
                }
            }

private StringBuilder BuildData()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<table>");
        sb.Append("<tbody>");

        //loop Repeater and get data here

        sb.Append("</tbody></table>");
        return sb;
    }
```

Im able to generate a PDF succesfully but my problem is i want the data to be printed in 3 pages at some conditions.

How can i acheive this?Please help me

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by adding page break in html table and it is working fine

```
<p style='page-break-before:always;'></p>
```